# Is there any way to check for properties of a class for a particular value in c#

Tags: c#

I have a License class.There are 50 boolean properties and some timestamp properties. I want to inform user in case all of these 50 properties are false.

One way is to use 50 if and if conditions.other way is reflection which seems overkill for this thing. Please suggest some other way. I am using .Net framework 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly do this with reflection:

```
var values = from prop in typeof(License).GetProperties()
             where prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool)
             select (bool) prop.GetValue(instance, null);

if (!values.Any(x => x))
{
    // Nope, everything's false
}
```

I'm not sure what you want to do about the timestamp properties...

Comment: Sir,what will you recommend in this case (above mentioned way or adding 50 IF)

Comment: @Jon, if you have a List of Licenses, how would you replace `instance` with a nested query? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Rohit: Well this is certainly simpler than 50 ifs... but I'm not sure I'd want 50 properties on the type to start with.

Comment: @Filip: You could certainly do it with a nested query. It wouldn't be terribly neat, but just using multiple "from" clauses should work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the strucutre of the class?

In that case if the boolean values are connected somehow you can use the following:

- [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx)
- [Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

And then to check the values just use a `for` or `foreach` loop.

Besides that, reflection is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at an [Indexed Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(VS.71).aspx). You could encapsulate the check into a read-only property of License:

```
private List<Boolean> props;

public bool IsExpired
{
    get { return !props.Any(p => p); }
}
```